# Merge not same length arrays of hashes based on key attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I would like to merge 2 arrays of hashes into 1 new array using JS, Underscore or JQuery.

Those 2 arrays could be different length and merge will be based on **id** attribute. Hashes in between same arrays may not have same id's , example:

arr1 id's = [1,5]

arr2 id's = [1,2]

Here are my arrays:

```
arr1 = [{
    id: 1
    name: 'fred'
},id: 5
    name: 'alex'
}];

arr2 = [{
    id: 1
    wage: '300'
},{
    id: 2
    wage: '10'
}]
```

so based on **id** attribute i should get following:

```
arr3 = [{
    id: 1
    name: 'fred'
    wage: '300'
},{
    id: 2
    wage: '10'
},{
    id: 5
    name: 'alex'
}]
```

I tried with [Merging/extend javascript object arrays based on join of a key property in each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059084/merging-extend-javascript-object-arrays-based-on-join-of-a-key-property-in-each) but if arrays are not same length it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: [JavaScript merging objects by id](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19480008/1529630)

Comment: @Mil - please clarify whether this needs to take into absolute account the `id` index, for example see my answer. You mention it, but not clear in example data or question, so update OP please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For an answer, consider that this is obvious duplicate post and see @Oriol  link. You can self answer and accept that, though compare those answers to others provided here before doing so

Comment: HI Daniel, thank you for helping with this one, but Oriol's suggestion didn't fix my problem (tried best answer). I also updated question maybe it is clearer now, i think @charlietfl got my point since i didn't explain it well in start - indexing could be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`:

```js
arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'fred' }];

arr2 = [
  { id: 1, wage: '300' }, 
  { id: 2, wage: '10' }
];

var result = [];
arr1.concat(arr2)
  .forEach(item =>
    result[item.id] =
    Object.assign({}, result[item.id], item)
  );
result = result.filter(r => r);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: When i try to convert this to coffeescript i get error because of fat arrow, could you explain you answer so i can convert it please?

Comment: This is simple first concatenate all your arrays and then use Object.assign to do then merge for you. Because the id is integer I used id as index of array and each time I change value of index with current value merge with item value. Consider to apply edit.

Comment: @mertezaT thank you, this worked very well, actually since indexing is based on int value can this work on strings? For example: id: "1" instead of id: 1 since i need string values not integers

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This solution, as noted in comments, does NOT account for matching via id. To see this in action, just add `{ id:7, name: 'wilma' }` to first array.

Im leaving it here however as it was NOT clear from example data or description this was key issue from the OP, though part fault on my part aswell. However I will comment there and if he says it is I may edit or remove this then

---

`jQuery.extend()`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

> jQuery.extend( [deep ], target, object1 [, objectN ] )

Passing in that extra param makes it a deep merge, ie recursive

https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/q0hhqbmf/

```
arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'fred'
}];

arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    wage: '300'
},{
    id: 2,
    wage: '10'
}]

arr3 = [];

// Use 2 extends, though $.merge(x,$.extend(y,z)) would work just as well in this case
$.extend(arr3, $.extend(true, arr1, arr2 ));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Fails when arrays not same length and indexing is different. Add `{
  id:7,
  name: 'wilma'
}` to first array

Comment: @charlietfl - run that code, it merged perfect in jsfiddle, all indexes and with exact data like that

Comment: Yeah but it only matches index...try adding object I just commented into first array. OP stated array lengths won't match

Comment: Unfortunately it's not smart enough to match based on common property value

Comment: @charlietfl - I actually didnt see that as part of OP, and reading OP again I still dont. I updated this and will comment there to ask that, then look again

Comment: I'm basing it off title...not trying to bust balls...just pointing out potential issue/limitation

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks for that, thats the OP problem for not clarifying, rather than removing lets help him actually fix it by using this as example

Comment: @charlietfl  Sorry if I didn't make it clear, i need to merging to be based on 'ID'

Comment: @DanielBrose Sorry for confusion, i need merging to be based on 'ID' attribute

Comment: @Mil - i figured that, please see my comment on OP and update data and description there to be clearer please

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply iterate them, and collect in new array?

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.13.1/dist/lodash.js"></script>
<script>
var arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'fred'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'alex'
  }
];

var arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    wage: '300'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    wage: '10'
  }
];
  
var a1, a2, arr3 = [], merged = [];
  
// finding intersection and merging
for(a1 = 0; a1 < arr1.length; a1++) {
  for(a2 = 0; a2 < arr2.length; a2++) {
    if(arr1[a1].id === arr2[a2].id) {
      arr3.push(_.extend(arr1[a1], arr2[a2]));
      merged.push(arr1[a1].id);
      break
    }
  }
}

// finding non merged elements and adding
for(a1 = 0; a1 < arr1.length; a1++) {
  if(merged.indexOf(arr1[a1].id) > -1) {
    continue;  
  }
  
  arr3.push(arr1[a1]);
}

// finding non merged elements and adding
for(a2 = 0; a2 < arr2.length; a2++) {
  if(merged.indexOf(arr2[a2].id) > -1) {
    continue; 
  }
  
  arr3.push(arr2[a2]);
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr3));
</script>
```